# How to interpret negative line number in stack trace

Tags: go

I made some changes to a fairly large project of mine today, and now I'm getting some odd behavior. Because I'm a knucklehead, I can't go back and figure out what I did.

But the main thrust of my question is how I should understand the negative line number in the stack trace that is printed. The `-1218` below is the one that I mean.

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x1 pc=0x80501f2]

goroutine 1 [running]:
server.init()              //     vv-------------RIGHT HERE
    /home/.../debugComponent.go:-1218 +0x282
_/home/.../possessions.init()
    /home/.../possessions.go:29 +0x42
_/home/.../pageWrap.init()
    /home/.../pageWrap.go:112 +0x47

main.init()
    /home/.../main.go:0 +0x3c

goroutine 2 [syscall]:

goroutine 3 [runnable]:
```

The associated `debugComponent.go` file is pretty non-essential right now, so I removed it to see what would happen, and the file name just gets replaced with a different one, and a different negative number.

I've had to find plenty of bugs while developing this app, but this one has got me stumped.

---

If it helps, there's the `main.go` and then several packages in play. The three files listed above are all different packages, and this seems to be happening during the imports.

---

I hope you've read this far, because here's the strangest part. If I add this declaration to `main.go`, the error goes away!

```
var test = func() int { return 1 }() // Everything is fine now!
```

Very confusing! It doesn't fix it if I do `var test = "foobar"`. It has to be the invoked `func`.

---

Any insight is appreciated, but mostly I'm curious about the `-1218` in the trace.

---

***Update***

I'm trying to get this down to a small example that reproduces the issue. After working on it I reverted back to my original code, and restarted the machine.

The first time I tried to build and run, two new entries were added to the top of the stack trace. But only the first time.

```
goroutine 1 [syscall]:
syscall.Syscall()
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/syscall/asm_linux_386.s:14 +0x5
syscall.Mkdir(0x83a2f18, 0x2, 0x2, 0x806255e, 0x83a2f1c, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/syscall/zerrors_linux_386.go:2225 +0x80
server.init()
```

So this would be in line with my main question about interpreting stack trace. The `-1218` is still there, but now there are these.

The `asm_linux_386.s` has this at line `14`:

```
MOVL    4(SP), AX       // syscall entry
```

I found the `zerrors_linux_386.go` too, but there's no line `2225`. The file stops long before that line.

Comment: FWIW, the `server` package is what I modified today, and it was little more than some really basic refactoring/organizing, and I was able to undo most of what I did. The source of the underlying issue is a deep mystery, and the very short stack trace isn't helping much. The package builds/installs perfectly.

Comment: What's your go version?

Comment: @wei2912: I tested with `1.0.3` and a `1.1 beta`. After `1.1` was released, I found and reported another bug (which existed in `1.0.3`) with respect to package initialization. That bug was fixed in `1.1.1`, though I haven't had a chance to retest this with that release to see if that bug fix or another one fixed this issue. I had however narrowed it down to some code that was in some ways similar to the bug I reported. I already refactored my project to resolve the issue, but I plan on going back to the faulty version when I have time to do more testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already reported and accepted as [Issue 5243](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5243).